# Checkpoints for source code in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Is it possible to create a checkpoint for a code in android studio? For example, if I create a code and then i want to revert all changes to some code i wrote for the same program earlier? Like we do in SQL using the setpoint command. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its called source control see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341276/what-exactly-is-source-control and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275229/what-is-source-code-control-for. Android Studio has built-in plugins for the most popular ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Git**:

- create a new repository.
  create a new directory, open it and perform a

`git init`

to create a new git repository.

- checkout a repository

create a working copy of a local repository by running the command

```
git clone /path/to/repository
```

when using a remote server, your command will be

```
git clone username@host:/path/to/repository
```

for more: [Git Guide](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide)